# How to reappear the image back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my project the objective is when i click on one image (e.g.northview) one image should display.
again when I click on another image (e.g southview) another image should overlap the previously existing image,and it should continue like that when I press the other button .

With the existing code it works only once .i.e if I press northview the image comes out ,if I press southview another image comes on top of it,but when I press again the northview the corresponding image does not come up.
Suggest me what to change in my code.

Here is my `custom.js`

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* INCREASE IMAGE SIZE ON MARKER BUTTON CLICK: PLAN PAGE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#southview").click(function() {
    $('.southviewpart').show();
    /*$("#leftpart").find("*").prop("disabled",true);*/

});

$("#northview").click(function(){
    $('.northviewpart').show();
});

$("#eastview1").click(function(){
    $('.eastviewpart').show();
});

$("#eastview2").click(function(){
    $('.eastviewpart').show();
});
});

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* HIDE IMAGE ON CLICKING IMAGE: PLAN PAGE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.southviewpart').click(function() {
    $('.southviewpart').hide();

});

$('.northviewpart').click(function(){
    $('.northviewpart').hide();
});

$('.eastviewpart').click(function(){
    $('.eastviewpart').hide();
});
});
```

Comment: use `toggle()` to show and hide like a button

Comment: Have you try to findout solution on google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions and solutions, however I modified my code a bit

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $("#southview").click(
            function()
            {
                $('.northviewpart').hide();
                $('.southviewpart').show();
                /*$("#leftpart").find("*").prop("disabled",true);*/
            }
        );

        $("#northview").click(
            function()
            {
                $('.southviewpart').hide();
                $('.northviewpart').show();
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Its working fine now.

some change by using toggle() method

```
 $('.northviewpart').hide();
    $('.southviewpart').hide();
$('#south').click(function() {
    $('.southviewpart').toggle();
  $('.northviewpart').hide();
});

$('#north').click(function(){
    $('.northviewpart').toggle();
     $('.southviewpart').hide();
});
```

Comment: So you only want one image to be shown at any given time? (hiding all images but the one that you just clicked?)

Comment: Then I suggest that you make ONE function that starts to hide all images in your navigation, and then shows the image that was clicked. From your original post it looks like you have many images. If they all have the same class, you can easily hide them all with one command, and then use `this` to show the one that was clicked.

Comment: @ some I will give it a try some time later
again thanks for your valuable ans and suggestions.